# How can I extract part of an IEnumerable based on known elements of the collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection, specifically an `IList<T>`. I know two elements within the collection, `startElement` and `endElement`.

Is there a LINQ query that will return the enumerable from `startElement` to `endElement`, inclusive?

I thought about using `sequence.SkipWhile(p=>p!=startElement).TakeWhile(q=>q!=endElement)` but that misses out the last element...

Comment: no, but it should be easy to create your own. If you clarify your requirements of what is acceptable someone can find duplicate or suggest  code.

Comment: If you know the two elements are in the list, in that order, then just use this query you have and `Concat` the `endElement` to the end. If you don't know if the elements are there in the required order, you'll have to fully materialize the required portion of the list anyway before returning even the first element to the caller (because you must not return anything if the `endElement` is not in fact there, or even throw an exception).

Answer (score 2):

George wrote a more flexible extension, you can find it in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31940000/5106041

Old version:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable <TData> InBetween <TData> (this IEnumerable <TData> Target, TData StartItem, TData EndItem)
    {
        var Comparer = EqualityComparer <TData>.Default;
        var FetchData = false;
        var StopIt = false;

        foreach (var Item in Target) {
            if (StopIt)
                break;

            if (Comparer.Equals (Item, StartItem))
                FetchData = true;

            if (Comparer.Equals (Item, EndItem))
                StopIt = true;

            if (FetchData)
                yield return Item;
        }

        yield break;
    }
}
```

So, now you can use it like this:

```
sequence.InBetween (startElement, endElement);
```

And it wont iterate the entire sequence.
Be aware that the are a lot of read made extensions in here http://linqlib.codeplex.com/

Comment: This will evaluate the condition for all elements in the sequence. I believe the point is to stop enumerating as soon as everything is taken.

Comment: But that's how linq works, it uses "linked" iterators, and to be fair, a reference comparison is very cheap, C# only compares the memory address.

Comment: Linq does not evaluate what it does not need to. `TakeWhile` will stop fetching elements as soon as the condition is false. Your code will continue fetching them (and discarding). If the sequence contains a million elements and the required ones are 1-10, your code will loop through the entire million and only return the first ten. `TakeWhile` will only loop through ten.

Comment: Oh, I see, i'll fix that.

Comment: You were right GSerg, linq doesn't provide an easy way to stop inside a predicate, I got used to it in database queries because I actually had to compare all rows or the server would already stop it for me.

Comment: Nice. Side note: 2 `foreach` (one to skip first part, another to iterate till end found) would likely produce much simple code.

Comment: Won't that reset the iterator? Please edit the post to use a simpler code :D

Comment: No, it won't if you use the same iterator, obtained with GetEnumerator. Check out my answer GetRangeUsingIterator on how to do it. It does not use additional branching in the conditional statements.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you don't want to use extra memory and don't want to exceed the algorithmic complexity of the underlying iteration method, so ToList, GroupBy, IndexOf are not alowed in my proposed implementations.

Also, not to place constraints on the element type, i'm using predicates.

```
    public static class EnumerableExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This one works using existing linq methods.
        /// </summary>
        public static IEnumerable<T> GetRange<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> isStart, Func<T, bool> isStop)
        {
            var provideExtraItem = new[] { true, false };
            return source
                .SkipWhile(i => !isStart(i))
                .SelectMany(i => provideExtraItem, (item, useThisOne) => new {item, useThisOne })
                .TakeWhile(i => i.useThisOne || !isStop(i.item))
                .Where(i => i.useThisOne)
                .Select(i => i.item);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This one is probably a bit faster.
        /// </summary>
        public static IEnumerable<T> GetRangeUsingIterator<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> isStart, Func<T, bool> isStop)
        {
            using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (iterator.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (isStart(iterator.Current))
                    {
                        yield return iterator.Current;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                while (iterator.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return iterator.Current;
                    if (isStop(iterator.Current))
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

These methods can be used as extension methods:

```
new[]{"apple", "orange", "banana", "pineapple"}.GetRange(i => i == "orange", i => i == "banana")
```

Comment: Just edited the GetRange method slightly. Removed an unneded Select.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can think of is:

```
var subSection = TestData.SkipWhile(p => p != startElement).ToList();
var result = subSection.Take(subSection.IndexOf(endElement) + 1);
```

Comment: ToArray rises memory requirements when it's not necessary

Comment: I needed to create the array in order to use the IndexOf method and memory consumption would be negligible, it would just be a shallow clone.

Comment: As the original question does not specify the size of iteration, you can never tell if it's negligible. On my current ETL project, i can hardly afford an entire collection in memory in many cases. The source ienumerable could bring billions of records from a database, and and the size of element can be high too. In case carefully enumerating with linq methods, these objects are made subject to garbage collection, and you could iterate virtually forever.

Comment: Bringing billions of records in from the database at once smells of bad application design. Anyway... I simply answered the question, whether it fits any particular situation or not is up to the developer to decide.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have not. Your code does not even compile, so nothing to discuss here. You can't make it a one-liner. Also it won't look just as nice when you you add all the required conditional statements associated with missing index for IndexOf operation.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use LINQ, but it's probably the most straightforward/readable approach.

```
        int startIndex = sequence.IndexOf(startElement), 
            endIndex = sequence.IndexOf(endElement);

        var range = sequence.GetRange(
                         startIndex, 
                         // +1 to account for zero-based indexing
                         1 + endIndex - startIndex
                    );
```

Note that this is technically less efficient than alternatives, but if you already have an IList in memory, the differences will likely be less than a millisecond which is a small sacrifice to make for readable code.

I'd recommend wrapping the code block with a Stopwatch to test against your specific situation to be sure, however.

Comment: This will evaluate the sequence three times.

Comment: True, but I suspect it's fine for the situation. If there's already an in-memory IList<T>, chances are there won't even be a millisecond difference vs. alternative approaches. Readability > sub-millisecond performance improvements, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

This will be the most efficient, as it doesn't create any unnecessary enumerator objects and only traverses the list one time.

```
var result = new List<T>();
var inSequence = false;

for (var i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
{
    var current = list[i];

    if (current == startElement) inSequence = true;
    if (!inSequence) continue;

    result.add(current);
    if (current == endElement) break;
}
```

This won't handle the case where `endElement` is missing, but you could do that pretty easily by assigning `result = null` as the last line of the `for` loop where `i = list.Length - 1`